# How can I select stats on lateness of a record expected x days after previous record?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have entities with config info in one table. If the 'vendor' doesn't do something within 'reminder_days' of the last time of doing it, then it becomes overdue.

```
    CREATE TABLE t_vendors
    (
      vendor_id NUMBER,
      vendor_name VARCHAR2 (250),
      reminder_days NUMBER
    );

    Insert into T_VENDORS (vendor_id, vendor_name, reminder_days)
    Values (12, 'sanity-test', 7);
```

and an app records what they do whenever they do it into this table with this sort of data:

```
    CREATE TABLE t_vendor_events
    (
        vendor_event_id,
        vendor_id NUMBER (19,0),
        description VARCHAR2 (250),
        event_date DATE
    );

    Insert into t_vendor_events (vendor_event_id, vendor_id, description, event_date)
    Values (10015, 12, TO_DATE('11/9/2015 21:22:55', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'one');
    Insert into t_vendor_events (vendor_event_id, vendor_id, description, event_date)
    Values (10016, 12, TO_DATE('11/16/2015 21:23:55', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'two');
    Insert into t_vendor_events (vendor_event_id, vendor_id, description, event_date)
    Values (10017, 12, TO_DATE('11/30/2015 21:24:55', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'three');
    Insert into t_vendor_events (vendor_event_id, vendor_id, description, event_date)
    Values (10018, 12, TO_DATE('12/01/2015 21:25:55', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'four');
```

Once I've got the comparative values, I need to aggregate the data to quantify the lateness:

- how many events occurred
- how often they were overdue
- what was expected (the reminder days value)
- how much they were late on average
- how much they were late at worst (max)

I need to see all the vendors in the result, including those that failed to produce an event at all.

All the solutions that I can think of involve creating extra columns and storing some kind of 'lateness' data on every event. This though strikes me as a redundancy, since I know the required interval (reminder_days) but I don't know what kind of nested selects would produce what I need.

I would prefer to stick to standard SQL and I'm not using PL-SQL, but am able to use Oracle-specific syntax in selects where necessary.

The result would look something like this (Expected Days is the 'reminder days' column):

```
Vendor    Event     Overdue   Expected   Avg       Max
          Count     Count     Days       Elapsed   Elapsed
Mega1     5         2         10         12        20
Ole!      6         0         10         9         10
GoPunk    0         0         0          0         0
X-Dan     0         0         0          0         0 
RetroB    1         1         30         60        60
```

Comment: Can you please add the expected output based on your sample data

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I put the SQL standards tag in there because preferably I am looking for a standard SQL solution rather than custom 11g - I figured the tag I need should be `Standard SQL` but there isn't one - and `SQL Standards` sounded like something to do with problems directly related to the definition of ANSI SQL rather than actual SQL problems, but there is no description - do you know any more?

Comment: The tag `sql` already refers to "standard/ANSI SQL"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag` to get the previous event_date and calculate the difference with the current event_date. Then select rows where the difference is > reminder_days by vendor. Just aggregate the final result, to know how often a vendor was late.

```
with prev as 
(select lag(event_date) over(partition by vendor_id order by event_date) prevdt
 , t.* from t_vendor_events)
select v.vendor_id, v.vendor_name, event_date - nvl(prevdt, event_date) diff 
from prev p
join t_vendors v on p.vendor_id = v.vendor_id
where event_date - nvl(prevdt, event_date) > v.reminder_days
```

Comment: I changed the `where` clause to add it as a join condition and made it a `left join`, otherwise you wouldn't see the vendors with no events.

Comment: I also added `AND prevdt IS NOT NULL` otherwise the first report with zero `lag` (which isn't really zero `lag`, it's null `lag`) will skew the stats